# Socket connection - Java adds bytes

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets

I want to send a string from my Android device to my node.js server through a socket. The connection works already, but whenever I send the string, the server receives additional characters.

This is what I receive when I send the String "hans" to the node.js server:

```
Buffer ac ed
Buffer 00 05 77 04 68 61 6e 73
```

as utf8 string:

```
??
♣w♦hans
```

Here is the Java part which sends the string:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",9988);
ObjectOutputStream clientOut = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());              

String sendString = "hans";             
clientOut.write(sendString.getBytes());
clientOut.flush();
```

So why does this happen?

Comment: What does your receiving code look like? And how were you expecting the receiver to know how long the string was?

Comment: Use just `OutputStream` instead of `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) which is used to send serialized Objects and must be decoded by an `ObjectInputStream` on the other end. If you are just sending bytes and reading bytes on the other end, then you should just be using an `OutputStream` and an `InputStream`.

Comment: Preferably a `Writer`, not a raw out/input stream.

Comment: You'll still need to encode the data somehow. Otherwise, the receiver will have no way to know where things begin and end. Basically, the OP just wrote code to send and receive data without first designing a *protocol* that specifies precisely what is to be sent, when, and how.

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` is not for sending primitive data types, but for any serializable data type in Java. I guess you are thinking of `DataOutputStream` when referring to primitives.